# Peter was with the protagonists at the Amity farm at the beginning of Insurgent. Why is that?

Tags: divergent

**Peter was with the protagonists at the Amity farm at the beginning of *Insurgent*. Why is that?**

I thought he was the one who tried to kill Tris in *Divergent* and whose body they found after he fell off (or was pushed off) higher ground near the Dauntless HQ.

Was he supposed to be a Divergent as well? He didn't have Tris' increased abilities in the 2nd round of training and I don't recall anything in *Divergent* indicating he was one of the Divergents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it might not be clear from the movies, Peter requests that Tris take him with them to Amity at the end of *Divergent*, because he's afraid of being killed by the leaders. He willingly offers up information about the simulations in return for some kind of safety - it's worth noting that he's also injured with a bullet wound at this point, so he's in no position to defend himself.

Tris also saves him from from the combined Erudite/Dauntless army raid against Amity, which slowly starts the process of them working together - he's ultimately something of a coward, but comes to his own decision about his loyalties.

> "I'm sick of doing bad things and liking it and then wondering what's wrong with me. I want it to be over. I want to start again."

Comment: @Hack-R The quote is from the books, I believe (sourced from the Wiki, I don't have my books on me but I recognize the quote). The movies did a rather poor job at explaining Peter's apparent change of heart, unfortunately.